# Best way to update over 12 million record Loop or no loop

Tags: mysql

I have over 12 million records in a table with over 6000 stocks data from the last 15 years. I am trying to update yesterday's price. Please see sample table below. The only method that I can think of to update yesterday's price is using script language. I am using C# to looping through all records. The first loop is to get all symbol, the second loop through each symbol from the first loop and update yesterday's price from one day before. This takes a very very long time. Any ideas, new methods, and other approach that speed up the process?

```
Symbol, todayis, price, yesterdayprice
----  ---------  ------  ------
aapl, 5/13/2015, 123.59, 124.45
aapl, 5/12/2015, 124.45, 122.24
aapl, 5/11/2015, 122.24, don't know
aapl, 5/10/2015, 127.41, don't know
```

Comment: Not enough info, is production uptime important to you?  If so have you heard of batch updates?  What about scheduling down time?  If speed is important to you think about batch updating these and schedule these batches at low usage times.

Comment: This is a backup database. Uptime is not important at all. Batch, you mean break them up in multiple batches?

Comment: this breaks normalization.

Comment: Updating millions of records will take time, especially if your schema isn't constructed to make it easy to do.

Comment: Normalization is not an issue here. What is important is speed to generate reports.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make this update with a single SQL statement, like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable y
                 ON y.Symbol=t.Symbol AND t.todayis = subdate(y.todayis, 1)
SET a.yesterdayprice = COALESCE(y.price, 'don't know')
```

This `UPDATE` tries to execute a self-join, matching the symbol and computing yesterday's date through `subdate(y.todayis, 1)` (`t` stands for "today", `y` stands for "yesterday").

When the corresponding row is found, `COALESCE` provides the value from it to the update. When the row is not there, `'don't know'` string is used as the default.

Comment: It says subdate is not recognized built functions. Also Yesterdays' price technically does not really mean yesterday there is the weekend and holidays. I should have said last transaction day price.

Comment: @user3690095 What is the type of `todayis` column? Is it a `date`?

Comment: @user3690095 That is strange, because `subdate` appears to be a valid built-in function for `date` columns ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate)).